# Mongoose Middleware - Determine whether to save new or update existing document

Tags: mongoose, save, middleware

I have a quite simple problem related to saving objects in Mongoose. I've searched for similar questions, but haven't come across anyone that matches my specific problem.

I'll provide a detailed explanation below, and finish with a short summary.

**Problem:**

Let's say I have a collection that looks like this.

```
var ObjectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var UserAnswer = new Schema({
  userId: {type: ObjectId, ref: "UserModel"},
  surveyId: {type: ObjectId, ref: "SurveyModel"},
  score: Number,
  timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
});
```

A thing to note here is that the `UserAnswer` schema doesn't have any unique indexes, meaning that a user can answer the same survey more than once.

However, if a user tries to answer a survey again (before a certain amount of time has passed) I'd like the latest existing UserAnswer document to be updated instead.

I could of course check this manually before saving a new object, but my question is if there's a smarter way to do it, e.g. through middleware?

I've looked at the `pre` and `validate` middleware options in the Mongoose API docs, but I'm not sure how I would implement this, since it seems like the `.pre("save", ..)` method either proceeds to save a new object or throw an error. I'm also not sure if `.validate()` could be used here, since it seems to be designed to validate single path's within a new object before saving, not **generally validate the whole object and determine whether or not to save a new object or update an existing one**, which is kind of what I need.

**Short version:**

Can I, through Mongoose middleware, determine whether to save a new Mongoose object or update an existing one. Example: If the query below returns data, update existing document, otherwise save new document.

```
UserAnswer
  .find({ userId: userId, surveyId: surveyId, timestamp: { $gte: startOfToday } })
  .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
  .limit(1)
  .exec(function(err, res) { ... })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your desired result could be achieved by using the `findOneAndUpdate` method, with the `upsert` option. This will insert a new record if one does not exist, or update the existing record if a match is found.

```
UserAnswer.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: userId, surveyId: surveyId, timestamp: { $gte: startOfToday } }, 
    {userId: userId, surveyId: surveyId, score: score, timestamp: Date.now()},
    {upsert: true, sort: {timestamp: -1}}, 
    function(err, doc) {
        //do something with the results
    });
```